# Programatically set the time server of a remote computer to match the control computer?

Tags: c#, windows, controller, client

I am coding in c# and I need to programatically synchronize a Client Computer's time server with a Controller Computer's time server. Similar to these steps for a Window's Computer.

1. In the task bar double click on the time.
2. Select Change Date and Time Settings > Internet Time > Change Settings.
3. Check the Synchronize with an Internet time server.
4. Select or manually enter the Server as 192.168.0.35
5. Click the Update Now button.
6. Verify that the time update is successful.
7. Close all windows.

I have looked online and on SO but haven't had much luck finding anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using Group Policy to set the time server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779145(v=WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by writing to the following registry:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters
```

(Altering the NtpServer string will give you what you want.)
If you're running as a user, then make sure the registry key has WRITE permissions.

Please see the documentation from MSDN at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/windows-time-service-tools-and-settings

It is recommended to use the w32time command (cmd.exe) to set the settings however.